# Fitting text in UILabel inside a Table View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using a TableViewController with "Right Detail" style cells. To fit the text into the `cell.textLabel` I use `cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()`. But the problem is, that the `cell.detailTextLabel` gets pushed out of the view. Whats the best way to solve this problem?

[This is the result I am getting right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM0gr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used `.sizeToFit()`, so i can't say what it is actually for but you don't need it. Lower the compression resistance of your label.

Content Compression Resistance explained:

```
Sets the priority with which a view resists being made smaller than its
intrinsic size. Setting a higher value means that we don’t want the view
to shrink smaller than the intrinsic content size.
```

Read more about it here: https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/ios-content-hugging-and-content-compression-resistance-priorities-476fb5828ef

Comment: Thank you very much. I've made a custom cell and by lowering the compression resistance of the left label I've managed to get the result I was looking for.

Comment: If this solved your problem please select it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest make your own custom cell.
1.you can crop left label if it is too wide.
2.expand left label to multiple lines and make cell height self constraint.